# File Api should delete preview when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery.fileapi

I'm trying to build a file upload and would like the preview to be cleared after clicking on the grey "Clear Content" button (it's in German). The file input element empties itself but the preview does not update itself.

Here is my Code:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" style=" height: 100px; max-width: 150px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 10px 5px 0 0;"/>'].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

My HTML Modal from Bootstrap 5

```
<div class="form-check">
  <div class="input-group">
      <!--<input type="file" class="form-control" id="files" name="uploaded_file[]" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,application/pdf" multiple="multiple"/>-->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-send" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
      <i class="fas fa-upload fa-2x"></i>
          <!--Dokumente hochladen-->
      </button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Bitte wählen Sie aus, welche Dokumente Sie hochladen möchten.</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="files" name="uploaded_file[]" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png, application/pdf" multiple="multiple" value=""/>
            <output id="list"></output>
            <small>
                <strong>
                    <br>
                    Hinweis: Es können <u>maximal 19</u> Dateien aufeinmal versendet werden! <br>Unterstützte Dateiformate: PDF, JPG und PNG
                  </strong>
              </small>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-send" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Weiter</button>
            <button type="button" id="clearFiles">Inhalte löschen</button>
              <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a picture of how it looks at the moment
[example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0sKL.png)

Comment: Your script is creating some `span` elements to be inserted before the `#list` element. Now when clicking the "Clear Content" button should target those `span` for removal. - I can't tell you exactly how to do it since you did not post any HTML and the button `click` handler. -- Edit your question.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have added my HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an event listener for the `Inhalte löschen` button:

```
// To clear the images
document.querySelector("#clearFiles").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector("#list").innerHTML = "";
});
```

Notice that I also changed the `.insertBefore(span, null);` in favour of `.append(span)`. So now the images are append INTO the `#list` div instead of BEFORE it. It makes it way easier to clear the whole content of `#list`.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image or PDF files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*') && !f.type.match('pdf')) {
      console.log(f.type)
      continue;
    }
    
    // A flag to know if the file is an image or a PDF
    let source_is_image = true;
    if(!f.type.match('image.*')){
      source_is_image = false;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        
        // Based on the flag, decide to use the image or the PDF logo
        var file = source_is_image ? e.target.result : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/PDF_file_icon.svg";
        
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', file, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
          ].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').append(span);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

// To clear the images
document.querySelector("#clearFiles").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector("#list").innerHTML = "";
});
```

```css
/* This can be in the CSS instead of inline style */
.thumb{
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <div class="input-group">
    <!--<input type="file" class="form-control" id="files" name="uploaded_file[]" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,application/pdf" multiple="multiple"/>-->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-send" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
      <i class="fas fa-upload fa-2x"></i>
      <!--Dokumente hochladen-->
    </button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Bitte wählen Sie aus, welche Dokumente Sie hochladen möchten.</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="files" name="uploaded_file[]" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png, application/pdf" multiple="multiple" value="" />
            <output id="list"></output>
            <small>
              <strong>
                <br>
                Hinweis: Es können <u>maximal 19</u> Dateien aufeinmal versendet werden! <br>Unterstützte Dateiformate: PDF, JPG und PNG
              </strong>
            </small>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-send" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Weiter</button>
            <button type="button" id="clearFiles">Inhalte löschen</button>
            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have another question @LouysPatriceBessette
If I want all PDF documents to have a specific image assigned to them, I should do the following:

Comment: if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" style=" height: 100px; max-width: 150px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 10px 5px 0 0;"/>'
        ].join('');
        } else {
            span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="images/PDFlogo.png" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" style=" height: 100px; max-width: 150px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 10px 5px 0 0;"/>'
        ].join('');
        }
right?

Comment: Probably... Does it work? -- I would use a class instead of the inline style. That would make the code more readable. ;)

Comment: Sorry am new here and have not yet figured out how everything works :D 
No, unfortunately that does not work so @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: Try my edit ;) I used a flag to know if the file is a PDF or an image... Then used this flag in the reader callback to decide about the image or PDF logo ;)

Comment: You know what? I love you! Works great! Big thank you @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: lol! You are welcome! ;)